# Rails Role Persistence Variable for User Details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have two types of users User and Host. Every Host is also a User but every User is not a Host.

> User(id, name, is_host = true/false)
>
> Host(id, name, user_id)

Like in Devise after login how we have the current_user variable avaliable i want to create a similar variable thats available every where when `is_host = true`

I have a Base controller called Host::HostController which has scoped paths.

Which is the best practice to have such variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add the following code in `application_controller.rb`:

```ruby
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_host

  def current_host
    if current_user && current_user.is_host
      current_user.host
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

This will either return the correct `Host` or `nil`, depending on whether the user is a host or not. Defining it as a `helper_method` allows you to use it in your views!

**EDIT**
Or you could use ternary!

```ruby
def current_host
  current_user && current_user.is_host ? current_user.host : nil
end
```

Comment: this is available as 'current_host' every where? why have u added helper_method :current_host ?

Comment: Yep! It's available in your controller by default, and defining it as a `helper_method` allows you to use it in your views!